# My QGIS keeps me returning "ascii" errors

Tags: qgis, python, error, ascii, unicode

First, whenever I open QGIS, the extension "Quickmap Services" returns an error with this tracker:

```
Impossible to load the extension quick_map_services because of an
error on calling  InitGui() method

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 20: 
ordinal not in range(128)  Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 315, 
in startPlugin plugins[packageName].initGui()  
File "C:/Users/Usu�rio/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\quick_map_services.py", line 112, in initGui self.build_menu_tree()
File "C:/Users/Usu�rio/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\quick_map_services.py", line 232, in build_menu_tree self.groups_list = DsGroupsList(self.locale, self.custom_translator)
File "C:/Users/Usu�rio/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\ds_groups_list.py", line 46, in __init__  self._fill_groups_list()
File "C:/Users/Usu�rio/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\ds_groups_list.py", line 53, in _fill_groups_list   self._read_ini_file(root, ini_file)
File "C:/Users/Usu�rio/.qgis2/python/plugins\quick_map_services\ds_groups_list.py", line 75, in _read_ini_file  error_message = 'Group INI file can\'t be parsed: ' + e.message
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 58, 
in showWarning  "warning:%s\ntraceback:%s" % (warnings.formatwarning(message, 
category, filename, lineno), stk), UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't 
decode byte 0xe1 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)


Versão do Python: 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500
32 bit (Intel)]  Versão do QGIS: 2.12.2-Lyon Lyon, b403532 

Caminho do Python: C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/Usuário/.qgis2/python C:/Users/Usuário/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:/Users/Usuário/.qgis2//python
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools
```

Also, there's another error for the extension "Processing" that returns this error:

```
Impossible to load the extension because of an error on calling the
classFactory() method

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position
20: ordinal not in range(128)  Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line
306, in startPlugin plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)   
File "C:/Users/Usu�rio/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line
37, in classFactory from processing.ProcessingPlugin import ProcessingPlugin   
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 572, in
_import  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   
File "C:/Users/Usu�rio/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\ProcessingPlugin.py",
line 47, in if cmd_folder not in sys.path:   
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 58, in
showWarning  "warning:%s\ntraceback:%s" % (warnings.formatwarning(message, 
category, filename, lineno), stk), UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec
can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)


Versão do Python: 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500
32 bit (Intel)]  Versão do QGIS: 2.12.2-Lyon Lyon, b403532 

Caminho do Python: C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/Usuário/.qgis2/python C:/Users/Usuário/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGISLY~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:/Users/Usuário/.qgis2//python
C:\PROGRA~1\QGISLY~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Renanxusa! Seems like there's an issue with your username "Usuário" containing an accent which can't be read correctly. Perhaps you could reinstall QGIS on a new username such as "Usuario" (without the accent)?

Comment: Will do that, but wouldn't every extension give off the same error? I have some others installed beyond those two.

EDIT: Thanks for the welcome! haha

Comment: I'm not much of a plugin builder but I am _guessing_ that some extensions contain code to convert username strings to unicode which takes into account the different characters. Hopefully someone can clarify this :)

Comment: There's a poblem here: While installing QGIS it doesn't give me an option to choose where the user folders will be installed so it installs into "Usuário" folder by default. I guess, changing that folder's name will be a problem for other apps to locate their files. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Instead of creating a new username, could you **change** it? If you can then also change the name of the user folder and re-install QGIS.

Comment: I don't know, this is strange. My username isn't actually Usuário, it's GEOPRO4, but for some reason, my applications use this Usuário folder instead of GEOPRO4 (which, in fact, has a .qgis folder in it)

Comment: Just tried chenging the folder name in the regedit "registeredowner", reinstalled qgis, and still nothing...

Comment: this has recently been logged as [an issue on the plugin repo](https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices/issues/28), looking at the code it seems having unicode characters in your path is the cause, as @Joseph suggested.